# How do I put raid target icons in chat?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World Of Warcraft, I see people using raid target icons in chat. How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although extremely annoying when people use them to spam trade, inserting icons into chat can be very useful for certain situations, especially for party/raid leaders (even tanks leading groups who want a macro that says "skull first, then x, sheep moon")

The easiest method for me is to put the name of the symbol in curly braces as such: {skull}
You can also reference them by number, which can save space in macros but is less clear what each icon is: {rt8}

The full list of icons are:

- [image: Star] {Star} / {rt1}
- [image: Circle] {Circle} / {Coin} / {rt2}
- [image: Diamond] {Diamond} / {rt3}
- [image: Triangle] {Triangle} / {rt4}
- [image: Moon] {Moon} / {rt5}
- [image: Square] {Square} / {rt6}
- [image: Cross] {Cross} / {X} / {rt7}
- [image: Skull] {Skull} / {rt8}

Comment: If used in a group of players with different languages, use {rt#} instead of {name}. A German client can not understand English target names, like {skull} or vice versa.

Comment: @dly True, but you can use {totenkopf} for skull, etc.

Comment: @AlexioVay correct, but only if everyone plays in German. *You* can see it, but any other language won't. You can easily try it by joining foreign realms. The trade chat spam with named icons won't show up properly.

Comment: I know that this is client-wise. I think this is pretty common sense.